# Why checkfield sends 'on' and not 'true' to the server | Extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a form with bunch of fields and checkfield:

```
            {
                xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Approved?',
                name: 'user[approved]',
                value: usersShowStore.getData().items[0].data.approved,
            },
```

And so if checkbox selected in request parameters approved value is 'on'.

```
Started PUT "/users/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-03 16:33:49 +0200
Processing by UsersController#update as */*
Parameters: {"user"=>{"first_name"=>"Test", "last_name"=>"Admin", "approved"=>"on", ...}
```

How to change checkbox default behavior to send boolean values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the default [`inputValue`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Checkbox-cfg-inputValue):

> The value that should go into the generated input element's value
>   attribute and should be used as the parameter value when submitting as
>   part of a form.
>
> Defaults to: 'on'

Comment: "In addition to the main boolean value, you may also specify a separate inputValue. You will want to set this value if you have multiple checkboxes with the same name. If not specified, the value on will be used"(from docs). Even if I change **value** to **inputValue** checkbox does not react to initial data `inputValue: usersShowStore.getData().items[0].data.approved` and sends 'false' eather checkbox is 'checked' or not.

Comment: Don't replace `value` with `inputValue`, leave `value` and add `inputValue: true`.